# cannot increment item in cart

Tags: reactjs, increment

i wanna increment the item quantity whenever i add an item to cart. My codes aren't working and i get the error "*Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')*" at my Cart.js and i don't know why. Can anyone help me? Thank you so much!

Codesandbox link:https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-shop-cart-forked-tlpek?file=/src/components/Cart.js

Comment: The reason is that you are not passing "cartItems" as props in your app.js. In order to fix this issue, either you need to pass empty value to the "cartItems" props from app.js or define default props in Cart.js

Comment: You are adding an item to a new variable "cartItems" but not updating the the state back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to pass the `cartItems` props from the parent (`app.js`) component.

```js
...
// in line no:75
 <Cart cartItems={this.state.cartItems} />
...
```

change your `addToCart` method aswell:

```js
// in line no: 19
addToCart = (product) => {
    const isInCart = cartItems.some((item) => item.id === product.id);
    let newCart = [];
    if (isInCart) {
      newCart = this.state.cartItems.map((cart) => {
        return {
          ...cart,
          quantity: Number(cart.quantity) + 1
        };
      });
    } else {
      newCart = [...this.state.cartItems, { ...product, quantity: 1 }];
    }
    this.setState({
      cartItems: newCart
    });
  };
```

You're expecting the `cartItems` props in your `cart.js` file but you didn't pass it from the parent component.

Comment: I fixed it, it works but when i click the add to add to cart button, the quantity in my cart doesn't increment. Can you help me? Update link: https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-shop-cart-forked-tlpek?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I've added `addToCart` method, if you need anything let me know. and if I've answered your question, please accept it. Thank you!

Comment: thank you , it works but the quantity stays as 1 no matter when i click 2 or more items...

Answer (score 0):

It's because in APP.js while calling `<Cart />` at line number 75, you are not passing the props but you are trying to access values from props in card.js at 4   `const { cartItems } = props;` so it will be undefined and length can't be read on undefined.

I suggest change line 75 in app.js to `<Cart cartItems={this.state.cartItems}/>`

Corrected:

```
addToCart = (product) => {
let alreadyIncart = false;
let cartItems = this.state.cartItems.slice();
cartItems.length !== 0
  ? cartItems.forEach((item) => {
      if (item.id === product.id) {
        item++;
        alreadyIncart = true;
      }
      if (!alreadyIncart) {
        cartItems.push({ ...product, count: 1 });
      }
    })
  : cartItems.push({ ...product, count: 1 });
this.setState({ cartItems: cartItems });
};
```

Comment: I fixed it, it works but when i click the add to add to cart button, the quantity in my cart doesn't increment. Can you help me? Update link: codesandbox.io/s/redux-shop-cart-forked-tlpek?file=/src/App.js

Comment: it's because you are not updating the state instead but a local variable that you have created is being updated, i can correct it?

Comment: Can you refer corrected section in my answer and replace it in your code and it will work?

Comment: I would appreciate an accept or upvote

Comment: thank you , it works but the quantity stays as 1 no matter when i click 2 or more items...